# Why does HP DeskJet 2620 add borders when printing 4x6 photos?

Tags: printing, printer

I have colour printer, Glossy `4*6 Inch` paper and requirement where I need to give `2*2 inch` photos

I decided to give it a go and print 6 `2*2 inch` photo's on a one `4*6 inch` glossy paper

What I did to produce image :

- created a project GIMP and opened the image
- select Crop tool and checked `fixed` Aspect ratio with 1:1 setting
- selected desired part of the image (Face area) and cropped
- opened cropped image in new frame ( by clicking on it)
- then created 6 tiles ( Filters ->  Map -> Tile )

  - width x 3 and height x 2 ( here I have disabled aspect ratio)
- Set Print size ( Image -> Print Size 6 inch x 4 inch)
- export image

When I print the image it miraculously adds 0.5 inch margin on the left side, 0.1 on right and 0.3 inch on bottom and 0.1 inch on top as a result none of the tiles will be of `2*2`

Center top tile will be close to it i.e. 2 inch width and 1.9 inch height

Not sure what I am doing wrong or where the problem is, any help appreciated to solve this mystery

Tried following Print options

- Default paper size : `4*6` as well as custom `102 * 152 mm` with 0 mm
  printable area on all side
- `selected scale to fit`  and `Print Entire image`
- Paper quality: Photo on Glossy paper - Fine

Printer: HP DeskJet 2620

Tool: Gimp 2.10

Original image ration (1:1) : 3000 x 3000 pixel

OS : MacOS Catalina

[image: look at the white area on 3 side, covered original image with sticky :D]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn't really a photography question, it's a hardware issue… but to throw you a bone - you need a borderless (edge-to-edge or full bleed) printer to do that. Very few domestic printers are capable.

Comment: ah! @Tetsujin thank for highlighting it, I was not familiar with the borderless printer concept and that explains it all,good to understand that my image processing and photo editing is not a problem here.. I will def close this

Comment: Even if you had a borderless printer, the middle two images would end up slightly larger than the other four images because a bit of the border of the image ends up outside of the print area. Whether that's acceptable depends on how strict the size requirement is.

Answer (score 1):

To print without any border, it is necessary to use a printer which supports borderless printing. It requires some mechanics to move the paper through the printer so that the head can place ink all the way to the edges.

The HP DeskJet  2620 clearly does not support this. Just check its [specifications](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-deskjet-2600-all-in-one-printer-series/12319824/document/c05524449#AbT7). Towards the bottom, it says:

> Borderless printing No